# Index Out of Range Exception in Thread Pooling in C# -Task.Run()

Tags: multithreading, async-await, task, threadpool, multitasking

When I remove Thread pooling or uncomment Console.WriteLine() from code then code works fine, but to improve performance I want to process each DataTable column on separate Task. It throws index out of range exception.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
private async void btnExcel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dt = new DataTable("worksheet");
        dt.Columns.Add("Id");
        dt.Columns.Add("MobileNo");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name1");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name2");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name3");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name4");

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            dt.Rows.Add(i, "99999", "ABC" + i, "n1", "n2", "n3", "n4");

        //var tasksInFlight = new Task[dt.Columns.Count];
        var tasksInFlight = new List<Task>();

        for (int index = 0; index < dt.Columns.Count; index++)
        {
            tasksInFlight.Add(updateDt(index, "col " + index));

        }

        //await Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasksInFlight, cT => { string a = "abc"; });

        await Task.WhenAll(tasksInFlight);

    }


    public async Task updateDt(int colNum, string data)
    {
        try
        {
            Task t = Task.Run(() =>
            {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                    // Console.WriteLine("Col Num : " + colNum + "  i = " + i);
                    dt.Rows[i][colNum] = data;
                }
            });

            await t;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `tasksInFlight.Add(updateDt(index, "col " + index));` the value of index is not read; you merely store a task that will be executed later - when you call `Task.WhenAll`.  It is when the tasks are executed when the value of `index` is evaluated.  Which happens after the loop is over and the value of `index` is now equal to `dt.Columns.Count`, which is out of the range of the array.

Read about C# closures [here](https://www.simplethread.com/c-closures-explained/).

To fix it, you can do like this:

```
for (int index = 0; index < dt.Columns.Count; index++)
{
    int tmpIndex = index;
    tasksInFlight.Add(updateDt(tmpIndex, "col " + tmpIndex));
}
```

---

**EDIT**: After further investigation it turns out that DataTable is not thread-safe.

In addition to the fix above, DataTable should be accessed in a lock:

```
 lock (dt) 
 { 
     dt.Rows[i][colNum] = data; 
 }
```

However, unless retrieving the actual data to put in the DataTable CPU-intensive, the lock eliminates all benefits of concurrency in this case.

Comment: Thank you, i tried your solution but still the same issue, some time code run smoothly but sometime get index out of range exception. please help .

Comment: exception throw at  dt.Rows[i][colNum] = data;

Comment: which is out of range - i or colNum?

Comment: when i debug and check 'i' and 'colNum' value is in valid range. Please help

Comment: Try to log the values on exception.

Comment: Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in mscorlib.dll
Col Num : 2  j = 33;


Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in mscorlib.dll
Col Num : 5  j = 60

Every time Exception throw at different index.

Comment: Yes, but which of the two violates the range?  colnum or i?

Comment: The strange thing is both in range.. some time application runs smoothly without any problem..

Comment: Then it is likely DataTable doesn't allow multi-threaded access.  Just to test, try this:

lock (dt)
{
   dt.Rows[i][colNum] = data;
}

Comment: So, you can't fix this.  Lock doesn't help you with performance, unless your code to retrieve the actual data is complex.  I will update my answer.

Comment: Okay, Thank you.